# How to servers my homepage with and HTML file and all others paths/urls with a PHP file

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

What I'm trying to achieve is if someone visit my home/index page, I need to server my `index.html` file. But, if it's another URL/path pass the request to my `index.php` file (I'm using Symfony).

I follow [this example](https://www.tollmanz.com/nginx-location-match-homepage/), but is not working. It's always serving my PHP file.

```
server 
{
    listen       80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    root   /path/to/my/web;
    index index.html index.php;

    location = /index.html 
    {
        try_files $uri /index.html?$args;
    }

    location / 
    {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

}
```

I will appreciate any help or guidance you can share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finally worked for me:

```
server 
{
    listen       80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    root   /path/to/my/web;
    index index.html index.php;

    location = / 
    {
        try_files $uri /index.html?$args;
    }

    location / 
    {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

}
```